# I can not add class instance to the list in another class. in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, class

I am trying to add class instance to the list but as i try it, it doesn't shown in the list. I checked if i am even taking the input. Yes i am taking the input, it correctly adds to list but it can not add the list in another class which is in another dart file.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
```

From my main dart file:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
List<Animes> animeler = [];
```

i have bunch of examples in animeler list as Animes instance. It does show it on screen but when i enter anything. it does not show the new one.

Add class:

```
class AnimeAdd extends StatefulWidget {

  List<Animes> animes = [];
  AnimeAdd(List<Animes> anime)
  {
      this.animes = animes;
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AnimeAddState(animes);
  }

}
```

i can take the input correctly. i know this from printing the animes list. Instance number gets higher every time i take input.

Where i try to take the list in main file:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      flex: 1,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Tıkla gör"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => AnimeAdd(animeler)));
```

Comment: This seems a State management issue, take a look at the following documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the problem correctly, but I guess the problem here is the cause :

```
   List<Animes> animes = [];
    AnimeAdd(List<Animes> anime){
     this.animes = animes;
     }
```

here you didn't use the `anime` value from the constructor, to save the constructor `anime` inside the `animes` :

```
List<Animes> animes = [];
    AnimeAdd(List<Animes> anime){
    this.animes = anime;
  }
```

the `this.animes = animes;` is like referring to the same object, but `this.animes = anime;` is a different thing, it will store `anime` inside `animes`

Comment: Yes that was a problem too. Thank you. Now it adds to the list, but it does not shown on the screen without doing hot reload. I am on android studio.

Comment: add `setState(() {
  this.animes = anime;
})`